# Double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate
$$ \int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^b z_1^n z_2^k \phi(z_1,z_2) dz_1 dz_2$$
where $ \phi(z_1,z_2)$ is a pdf of bivariate normal distribution and $n,k$ are natural numbers. Are there any tricks how I can do it? For instance, I had to evaluate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z_1^n z_2^k \phi(z_1,z_2) dz_1 dz_2 $$
and I could use a recursive formula to do that, however, that method does not work for both half-finite integrals. I would be very grateful if you could tell me some tricks if you know.